# Centos7: How to change desktop icons size?

Tags: centos7

After Centos updated recently the desktop icons became huge.

How do I make them smaller again?

Edit: I already tried
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level small`
but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open any folder explorer, and hit the options (3 lines) in the top right corner, and use the `- ##% +` buttons to change the icon size.  (This also modifies the desktop icon size.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On CentOs Linux 7, to reduce the desktop icon size, right click the icon and select `Resize icon` from  the drop-down menu.

For the folder icons, use the solution suggested by @selenium (though it no more effects the desktop icons)

[image: image showing the + and - zoom buttons when a folder is opened]